# How can I add a request header with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2

I want to use AFNetworking class to my application to communicating with server.

I am new to this library . Here is my code:

```
 NSDictionary *user=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"hiteshp",@"userName",@"12345^",@"password", nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.requestSerializer=requestSerializer;   //[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:@"myURL" parameters:user success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@ %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I want to add header to this request . I tried but it is not working . If I wrote commented line then request is done but I also want to add one more field "Authorization" to requset.
Andhow to print request header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in your code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", @"application/json", nil];

//Authorization    
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:userName password:password];
```

Comment: Getting an error that property 'acceptableContentTypes' not found on object of type 'id<AFURLResponseSerialization>'

Answer (score 8):

I know it's too late but here's a code that makes what you want

```
NSString *finalyToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",user.token];
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://server1.appscserver.de/api"]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:finalyToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Thanks for replying joan..I have now good experience with AFNetworking.

Comment: @vivek I am also trying to send Authorization bearer header, but not working.. 401 Unathorized. I think '[manager.requestSerializer setValue:finalyToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];' is not the correct way to set the Auth. header

Comment: @Nil it has always worked for me, maybe the name of the header field is different, on the project I am working now it's called "X-Auth". "Authorization" is the most common one but make sure you are using the correct one.

Comment: @Nil and of course "Bearer" it's optional too, depends on your webservice. Sometimes with just the token is enough.

Comment: The bug was actually the cause of a buggy setter method which was setting the bearer string nil. Anyways thanks. Cheers..

Answer (score 2):

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Answer (score 0):

in php file add:
`header('Content-type: application/json');`

in xcode:
`manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];`

example xcode code:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"key1": @"value1",
                             @"key2": @"value2"};

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", Url] parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

Comment: i think you got error `"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"`, if yes, then this solution help you. Of course response from server send in Json format like `json_encode($response)`. if no, sorry.